# How do I open a Java program using C++

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to make a Java program, but I want it to be opened by C++.

I have been this using in C++

```
system("java -jar MMQ4.jar");
```

But it requires the users to add C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\ to their PATH environmental variable

So, is their another way to run a Java program using C++?

Comment: Somewhere, somehow, the path to Java must be specified. Another option is to specify the path in the system() command itself.

Comment: How do you run the Java program from the command prompt?

Comment: im guessing he doesnt know himself :-)

Comment: Package a copy of the java jre with your application. Then you can run the java app referencing your copy of the jre

Comment: I do know how to open a java program.

Answer (score 1):

running java files does NOT require the user to add something to environment variables, thats simply wrong as the Java-installer already does that automatically.

If you cant run the the java-binary without adding something to the environment your JRE is faulty and you need to reinstall. Please dont believe everything you read on internet forums, this statement is a really old myth, it was true about 5 years ago for JDK-releases but everyting after that .... not so much

Comment: I kinda tested it. And people who ran the installers did not havae access to the java command

Comment: either they're lying or they're installing VERY old versions of java (i believe pre- 1.6). Simple as that. Maybe some non-oracle installers might also give you a faulty setup, of course oracle-java is best java

Answer (score 0):

One solution, not nice in my opinion is:

```
system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"<java_path>\" && java -jar MMQ4.jar");
```

This solution is valid for unix s.o.

For windows, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx).

## update:

By the way, if I understand what are your intentions, you should use:

```
fork
exec
wait
```

rather than system.

```
const int pid = fork();
execv("java", "-jar MMQ4.jar"");
```

In this way you have a reference to PID's process and kill it when you want.

Comment: You can also change the enviroment for a process before you run it.

Comment: Sry. I am really new at C++

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `-classpath` option to the Java interpreter.  It's been some time since I've used Java, but in the past, that would have worked.